# Prove $R$ conatins an ideal that is not finitely generated. $R = F[x,x^2 y,\ldots,x^n y^{n-1},\ldots]$

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, integral-domain

Prove R conatins an ideal that is not finitely generated. $R = F[x,x^{2}y,\ldots,x^n y^{n-1},\ldots]$ and is a subring of $F[x,y]$ where $F$ is a field.

Seems like $R$ itself is not finitely generated and $R$ is an ideal of itself. Im just not positive this would work or really how to show it.

Say $I \le R$ is an ideal and if $I$ were finite then for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, $I = \{x^{k+1} y^k \mid0 \le t \le n \}$

this is where I get stuck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ideal $R$ is generated by $(1)$. Remember that for this, you are allowed to multiply by any element in $R$. So for example $x^2y$ is in $(1)$ since $x^2y = (x^2y) \cdot 1$.

Your statement about $I$ is not correct. For example, $I = (x^2y + x^3y^2)$ is finitely generated but not of the form you claim.

To solve the exercise, you want to find some ideal that is not finitely generated. One choice here is $I = (x, x^2y, x^3y^2, \dots)$. The trick is to show that it is not finitely generated. Suppose $I$ is equal to $(x, x^2y, x^3y^2, \dots, x^{N+1}y^N)$. Then is $x^{N+2}y^{N+1}$ in $I$?

Comment: sorry my statement about $I$ was incomplete I was trying to figure out where to go from there.  Seems that $x^{N+2}y^{N+1}$ is not in $I$
for instance $x \in R$ and $x \cdot x^{N+1}y^{N} = x^{N+2}y^{N}$ and also $x^{2}y \in R$ but $x^{2}Y \cdot x^{N+1}y^{N} = x^{N+3}y^{N+1}$ Is that what needs to be shown? How does that show its not finitely generated?

Comment: oh I think I get the not finitely generated part now.

Comment: @oliverjones: Your last comment makes it sound like you have figured it out. Let me know if this is not the case.